# No method matching error for a function I updated on my personal Julia package

Tags: julia

I have a personal package called `VFitApproximation` and there is a function in there called `vfitting` . I added a few more parameters to that function after updating my package. I have used Revise, I have removed and added the package to update the library. In fact when I follow the link to the file where the error is coming from, that file has all the reflected changes!
The error is:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching vfitting(::DataFrame, ::Int64, ::Vector{ComplexF64}; tol=1.0e-10, weightvec=Float64[], force_conjugacy=true)
Closest candidates are:
  vfitting(::DataFrame, ::Int64, ::AbstractVector{T} where T) at /home/shubhang/.julia/packages/VFitApproximation/gu1hv/src/VFitApproximation.jl:292 got unsupported keyword arguments "tol", "weightvec", "force_conjugacy"
  vfitting(::DataFrame, ::Int64, ::AbstractVector{T} where T, ::Float64) at /home/shubhang/.julia/packages/VFitApproximation/gu1hv/src/VFitApproximation.jl:292 got unsupported keyword arguments "tol", "weightvec", "force_conjugacy"
  vfitting(::DataFrame, ::Int64, ::AbstractVector{T} where T, ::Float64, ::AbstractVector{T} where T) at /home/shubhang/.julia/packages/VFitApproximation/gu1hv/src/VFitApproximation.jl:292 got unsupported keyword arguments "tol", "weightvec", "force_conjugacy"
  ...
```

The function in question is, in the file where the error is coming from

```
function vfitting(f_df::DataFrame, m::Int, ξ::AbstractVector, tol::Float64 =1e-10,  weightvec::AbstractVector = Float64[], force_conjugacy::Bool=false)
```

The way I called the function is

```
approx, err = VFitApproximation.vfitting(spectra_df[:,[1,j]], 10, starting_ξ, tol=1.0e-10, weightvec=Float64[] ,force_conjugacy=true)
```

I don't know how to fix this, the file and function seem fine but the error continues!

Comment: In definition, replace comma `,` between `ξ::AbstractVector` and `tol::Float64 =1e-10` with semicolon `;` to signify beginning of keyword arguments

Comment: Did previous comment resolve the issue? Should I post it as answer?

Comment: Yes that solved the problem! Yes please post it as an answer I will checkmark it and upvote it! Thanks a lot, I learnt about keyword arguments and positional arguments today! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first detailed in a comment:

In function definition, replace comma `,` between `ξ::AbstractVector` and `tol::Float64 =1e-10` with semicolon `;` to signify beginning of keyword arguments.

In general, Julia needs to know how to differentiate between positional arguments and keyword arguments. In function definition this is done by separating them with a semicolon (`;`), but in function invocation the semicolon is optional and both `fun(a1, a2, kw1=v1)` and `fun(a1, a2; kw1=v1)` are allowed. The latter (with the `;`) is recommended.